# MVC - error messages

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm creating MVC web application.

In which part of MVC (model-view-controller), I should save my error messages, that can appear where something goes wrong and user should read them?

Situation at the moment:

**Model:**

```
function f()
{
    $data[error] = "Error message"
    return $data;
}
```

**View:**

```
echo $error
```

Answer (score 3):

My opinion would be to have them at the ***model's end***. For me, the controller just acts as a middleman, and the view should not have to do much thinking..

The `VIEW` in my code simply prepares the front end output, after being given the data it needs to display in the page. It doesn't have to do any thinking, and all validations are in the model already, so it just has to focus on displaying results, forms, information, help, hint, etc.

The `CONTROLLER` in my code just does the communication for the user (client's browser requests), the model (which does all the thinking) and the view (which does all the 'showing'). It wouldn't know that there are errors in the input coming from the user; it merely passes the input to the model. When the model's done, the controller just passes that output to the view.

The `MODEL` in my code is responsible for doing all the thinking. It receives the input from the user (via the controller) and does what it needs to do with it. For any or all results and/or errors it generates, it just passes it to the view (again, via the controller) and expects that the view knows what to do: to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could possible throw an exception in your controller, and then catch them in your view handler.

Comment: For example I have **Registration** controller, and how I can show error message to my users, for example ('nickname already registered') etc. Now message are written in the model, but I think it's not correct

Answer (score -1):

A generic pattern would be:

*Define* in **Model**.

*Generate* in **Controller**.

*Display* in **View**.

You could store the error messages in session or pass them directly from controller to view.

Comment: No. Generate in Model. Control the generation in Controller.

Comment: @NoICE Fair, but that doesn't really add anything. Looking at my answer again, I would update it to add 'Define in Model'. ...which I just did :)